# Urrlib3/Requests: HTTPS problems on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl, python-requests

Hi I am trying to make an HTTPS connection using requests on App Engine but I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'CERT_NONE' is not defined
```

It seems that urrlib3 cannot import ssl. Any ideas?

Update: The problem is that ssl on App Engine is missing the following

```
from ssl import wrap_socket, CERT_NONE, SSLError
```

Comment: Do you have a complete traceback?

Comment: Bottom line is this one:   File "/Users/panosjee/Sources/Python/myapp/app/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/util.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ssl import wrap_socket, CERT_NONE, SSLError

ImportError: cannot import name wrap_socket

Comment: The fix has been pulled into master. Could you try it again, or post a short codesample which doesn't work? Sorry for posting this as an answer, missing rep.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was fixed by **t-8ch** as you can see on this call https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/130 at urllib3 github repository.

They have not done the merge to master branch yet, but you can get the available package from the fixed branch of **t-8ch** here: https://github.com/t-8ch/urllib3/tree/unify_ssl_api

I have tested and this is working well.

Comment: After cloning and compiling, the error changed for me: `ImportError: cannot import name wrap_socket`

Comment: Yeah, although I was able to download and install his modified urllib3, I'm still getting the same error when trying to install requests.

Answer (score 0):

The fix mentioned by maxcnunes appears to have been merged into requests-1.2.0. Looks like it's working on my dev_appserver at least.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the latest urllib3? They recently added support for GAE. I seem to recall you need to use the urlfetch API, rather than SSL directly.

Comment: Yes I do. I just patched CERT_NONE to 0 and works now but this is not a solution.

Comment: Wait, is this using devserver? I had the same problem, I think it works on production. Deploy it and check. Shitty, but I seem to recall that that's the case.

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work in production.  Anyone know of a fix?